# создание DLL на языке C

Tags: c, dll

Как создать динамическую библиотеку на языке C и подключить ее к проекту на языке **C** с помощью компилятора **Cygwin/gcc** в командной строке?

Так я сделал и подключил (код ниже) с префиксом **lib** и расширением .so, а вот как с расширением **.dll**, подскажите. Спасибо.

***sum.c***

```
#include "sum.h"

int f1(int a, int b) {
 return a + b;
}
```

***sum.h***

```
int f1(int, int);
```

***main.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sum.h"

int main(void) {
 printf("%d", f1(10, 20));
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

создание динамической библиотеки

> gcc -shared sum.c -o libsum.so

компиляция проекта с динамической библиотекой

> gcc main.c -o abc.exe -L . libsum.so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcc -shared -o libsum.dll sum.c
gcc -L. -o abc.exe main.c -lsum
```

Comment: Уважаемый Sergey Gornostaev! Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: @Anton [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Уважаемый Sergey Gornostaev! Через 6 минут. Так сайт пишет.

Comment: Уважаемый Sergey Gornostaev! Проголосовал! Еще раз спасибо!